# Bash Files - /etc/profile vs ~/.bash_profile file

Tags: bash, bashrc

Does anyone know what the difference between the /etc/profile and the ~/.bash_profile file is? Which one is executed first?

Comment: Note that neither one is sourced (they are not executed anyway) when you open a new terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a  non-inter‐
   active  shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes com‐
   mands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.   After  reading
   that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile,
   in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one  that
   exists  and  is  readable.  The --noprofile option may be used when the
   shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
```

This was taken verbatim from `man bash`. Man is your friend :)